# antisamy-esapi.xml not found when trying to use OWASP ESAPI

Tags: java, resources, owasp, esapi

I have been trying to eval the OWASP ESAPI library, but have been having issues just getting it to initialize properly. I set up a resources folder for ESAPI.properties and validation.properties and those are loaded from the classpath without issue. However the antisamy-esapi.xml file is not loaded from classpath, and I found a bug from 2010 mentioning this. The errors I get are:

> Attempting to load antisamy-esapi.xml as resource file via file I/O.
>   Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: C:\Users\mydir\resin-pro-4.0.27\antisamy-esapi.xml
>   Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi\antisamy-esapi.xml
>   Not found in 'user.home' (C:\Users\mydir) directory: C:\Users\mydir\esapi\antisamy-esapi.xml

I am deploying the application using this library to resin. I have tried manually placing the xml file in all of the locations above, and the only one that finally worked was my home directory, which doesn't work very well for a production deploy.

I also followed a recommendation found elsewhere that says to set the -Dorg.owasp.esapi.resources property. This didn't work either, but more interestingly the error did not change, which makes me think that the setting was not picked up for some reason.

Any pointers on where this file needs to be located in my project so that it is loaded properly once deployed to the container?

Thanks in advance.

Update:

So from digging through the code it appears that there is specialized function for loading ESAPI.properties, which is why that file is able to be loaded from a standard resources (or any other src dir) directory which is deployed to the container. However the loading function for antisamy-esapi.xml just checks a particular directory under user.home, a configured custom directory, or via the result of ClassLoader.getSystemResource(). Not sure why these routines are separate. After hours of messing with this I lost patience and copied DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java and corrected the getResourceFile() method to use the same lookup code as loadConfigurationFromClasspath(). I then call ESAPI.override() with this class and it seems to work properly now.

Comment: The documentation for esapi warns to *NEVER* use the ESAPI.override() method in production code.  This should be noted for future question searchers.

Comment: The java property should have worked, were you able to verify through logging whether or not the webserver picked it up?  If you're running locally, you might be able to see if the property was passed by examining the server process with a tool like procexp.

Comment: Here's the relevant [reference](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/issues/detail?id=170).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work by adding the following line for esapi resources:

```
System.setProperty("org.owasp.esapi.resources", "src/main/resources");
```

[DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java](https://github.com/jackyu1978/owasp-esapi-java/blob/a6914588783e1c752f4cc4b08d99ee2d7dddacda/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java)

At least now I am able to use `instance.getValidSafeHTML`

However, it wont work when one deploy to web server. I guess the patch is required to load the `antisamy-esapi.xml` to load from the class path.